# Why PHP writes session to Redis twice?

Tags: php, apache, session, redis

Im using Redis to store php session data. This is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
$_SESSION['counter'] += 1;

echo "Hello World " . $_SESSION['counter'];
echo "<hr />";
```

On each page refresh, the counter is incremented twice, instead of once. The following like of code makes two entries into the numbers array, instead of one:

```
$_SESSION['numbers'][] = rand(1, 999999);
print_r($_SESSION['numbers']);
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Is this code in `index.php` in the root and do you have a `.htaccess`-file with some rewrite rules?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, the code is in index.php. I've the following rewrite rules:


`<Directory "/var/www/html"> AllowOverride All Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controller RewriteRule ^/index.php - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </Directory>`

Comment: Then my guess is that it's the famous favicon-issue. When you visit your site, the browser tries to not only load index.php, it also tries to request the favicon. If you don't have a favicon, that request will also enter your htaccess and get rewritten to index.php, making your code trigger twice per request. You can either add a favicon, check if the request is for `/favicon.ico` (either in PHP or the web server config) and return 404 if it is. I don't have the exact syntax here now though

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I can see that in the Dev tools network tab. You're right. Why didn't I look at that before? Thanks. Why don't you write it as a regular answer so that we can accept it?